# When compiling tensorflow from source, libcublas.so.8.0, libcufft.so.8.0, and libcurand.so.8.0 are not found

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to compile tensorflow with GPU support. The problem is when building with bazel, I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcublas.so.8.0, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcufft.so.8.0, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libcurand.so.8.0, needed by bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/_solib_local/_U_S_Stensorflow_Scontrib_Slite_Stoco_Ctoco___Utensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

However, those files do exist and they are in the directory that I told the config tool. They are in /usr/local/cuda/lib64. I am able to run the examples, so it appears to be installed correctly. I also know that it can find some of the files in that directory because if I give the tool the wrong file path, it immediately reports not finding the files.

Other similar questions are usually resolved by adding lines to their ~/.bashrc. I think I have all the correct lines, but I have included it below.

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
export LD_LIBRARY=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=${CUDA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
```

Anyone who can give any insights into where tensorflow is looking for the files or what I might be doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the libraries are in `/usr/local/cuda/lib64` then why have you set `CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0`?

Comment: I should have said. /usr/local/cuda is a sim link to /usr/local/cuda-8.0

Comment: I removed the CUDA tag for a reason. This is a question about building tensorflow and has nothing to do with CUDA programming, per se. You say you have a working CUDA installation, so this isn't a CUDA problem, it is a tensorflow problem